# Making a view of all tasks - unexpected 'SHOW'

Tags: scheduled-tasks, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, create-view

I would like to create a view that shows a full list of active and inactive tasks. Is there a way to do that?

Context: I'm making some automatic reporting that alerts us on failed tasks or inactive tasks.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "DB"."PUBLIC"."SNOWFLAKE_TASK_LIST" COPY GRANTS AS
SHOW tasks IN "DEV"."PUBLIC";
```

Gives me the error: unexpected 'SHOW'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no tasks, but give I suspect this a SHOW thing verse a task thing, I will substitute USERS:

```
use role accountadmin;
show users;
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "DB"."PUBLIC"."SNOWFLAKE_USERS_LIST" AS
SHOW users;
```

it would seem that SHOWs are not SELECTs. which makes sense, when given they are different, they give results that appear like table base results, but a number of setup functions are not true tables in the sense they are in Postgres.

This can further be seen in the fact

```
select * from (
    show users
);
```

gives the error

> SQL compilation error: Object 'SHOW' does not exist or not authorized.

[image]

and yet

```
SHOW users;

select * from table(result_scan(-1));
```

works.

But maybe the [TASK_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/task_history.html) table info table has your needed details, OR maybe the show command does work inside a stored procedure, thus you can asses the result_scan(-1) to capture the details.

Comment: even there is no column in `show tasks` that can tell inactive task.

Comment: haha, shows you how little I understood the applied question, and was talking in the abstract.

Comment: Please keep doing that , i am very much dependent on your's, Gokhan Atil , and Mike Walton posts to learn Snowflake here. ;)